# OpenCV Assertion failed Error - better solution for traversing through Mat objects? (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I've worked along some examples to create a motion detector in C++ with OpenCV, that draws a rectangle around a moving object.

When running the code, the following error pops up:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed <0 <= I && I < vv.size<>> in cv::*InputArray::getMat*, file C:\Users\grapeot\Source\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 1192

After some research I came to the conclusion that this probably has to do with the **looping through *cnts*** (see code below). In python **traversing through a Mat object** is very simple, but for C++ this was the best way I came up with.

**How can I fix this error or maybe find a better solution for the loop? (if the error is even related to this part)**

These are the examples: [Python Tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/) [Python Example](https://chelseatroy.com/2017/09/09/building-a-motion-detector-to-learn-opencv/) [C++ Example](http://ferdinandsilva.com/code/6d2beee53038ebe8abd98063abfdad86/)

And this is my code:  (sorry, couldn't get it properly formatted in here)

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
Mat frame,
    gray,
    frameDelta,
    thresh,
    firstFrame;
vector<vector<Point>> cnts;
Rect rect;
Point pt1, pt2;
VideoCapture cap(0);
String text;

cap >> frame;
cvtColor(frame, firstFrame, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
GaussianBlur(firstFrame, firstFrame, Size(21, 21), 0, 0);

if (cap.isOpened()) {
    while (true) {

        cap >> frame;

        if (frame.empty()) {
            break;
        }

        text = "No motion detected";

        // convert image to grayscale
        cvtColor(frame, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        // blur image to decrease sensitivity of motion detection
        GaussianBlur(gray, gray, Size(21, 21), 0, 0);

        // compare current and previous frame, store result in frameDelta
        absdiff(firstFrame, gray, frameDelta);

        // we only look for differences larger than a certain threshold
        threshold(frameDelta, thresh, 10, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
        dilate(thresh, thresh, Mat());
        findContours(thresh, cnts, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        for (int i = 0; i < cnts.size(); i++) {
            if (contourArea(cnts[i]) < 500) {
                continue;
            }

            // calculate box surrounding the contours
            rect = boundingRect(cnts);
            pt1.x = rect.x;
            pt1.y = rect.y;
            pt2.x = rect.x + rect.width;
            pt2.y = rect.y + rect.height;

            // draw the box
            rectangle(frame, pt1, pt2, (0, 255, 0), 2);
            text = "Motion detected";

        }

        putText(frame, text, Point(10, 20), FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2);
        imshow("Bounding Rectangles", frame);
        imshow("delta", frameDelta);

        if (waitKey(1) == 27) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cnts` is a `std::vector`, not a `cv::Mat`. Use `rect = boundingRect(cnts[i]);`. Use a debugger

Comment: I think I was a little bit to quick with this post, it has to do with the the call of the findContoursfunction just above the loop. I just commented it out the error disappeared. Either I can figure it out myself now or I'll start a new post, sorry this one here is misleading

Comment: The rest of the code seems correct. Only put the grab of the first frame after you check cap is opened

Comment: Without checking back on this post I've gone through the code again and after rethinking it I noticed my mistake by myself :D thank you nevertheless!